# Delete parent object when all children have been deleted in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, associations, relationship

Let's say I have the following relation:

`Reference(slide_id, group_id)` where reference is the association of a slide and a group.

One slide can be used in many references (with a different group): primary key is `slide_id` + `group_id`, which must be unique.

I want to have all the references deleted when either of the pointed group or slide are deleted.
Which I do by adding a cascade in the backref of the relationship:

```
# definition of Reference model

slide = db.relationship(
    Slide,
    backref=db.backref('references', cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan')
)

group = db.relationship(
    Group,
    backref=db.backref('references', cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan')
)
```

I also want to have the referenced group or slide deleted, whenever I delete a reference and there are no other references that use said group and/or slide.

I have thought about using `@listens_for(Reference, 'after_delete')` to manually delete parents when needed. I also tried attribute combos in the relationship, but I am not really sure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that idea with [`@listens_for`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html#sqlalchemy.event.listens_for) is not bad. You need just listen for `Reference` [`before_delete`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_delete). Below is an example that can help.

```
class Slide(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'slide'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship('Reference')
    references = db.relationship('Reference', back_populates='slide')


class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'group'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    references = db.relationship('Reference', back_populates='group')


class Reference(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reference'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    slide_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('slide.id'))
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
    group = db.relationship('Group', back_populates='references')
    slide = db.relationship('Slide', back_populates='references')


@event.listens_for(Reference, 'before_delete')
def delete_reference(mapper, connection, target):
    # after_flush used for consistent results
    @event.listens_for(Session, 'after_flush', once=True)
    def receive_after_flush(session, context):
        # just do here everything what you need...
        # if our preference slide is the last one
        if target.slide and not target.slide.references:
            print('add slide with id = %s to delete' % target.slide.id)
            session.delete(target.slide)
        # if our preference group is the last one
        if target.group and not target.group.references:
            session.delete(target.group)
            print('add group with id = %s to delete' % target.group.id)
```

Let's check it:

```
# clear tables
Reference.query.delete()
Group.query.delete()
Slide.query.delete()
# create one reference with only 1 group and only 1 slide
reference = Reference(group=Group(), slide=Slide())
db.session.add(reference)
db.session.commit()

print('reference with id %s was created. slide_id = %s, group_id = %s' % (
    reference.id, reference.slide_id, reference.group_id
))
reference = Reference.query.filter_by(id=reference.id).first()
print('add reference with id = %s to delete' % reference.id)
db.session.delete(reference)
db.session.commit()
print('amount references after delete: %s' % Reference.query.all())


# create 2 references but with the same group and slide
group = Group()
slide = Slide()
reference = Reference(group=group, slide=slide)
reference2 = Reference(group=group, slide=slide)
db.session.add(reference)
db.session.add(reference2)
db.session.commit()
print('reference with id %s was created. slide_id = %s, group_id = %s' % (
    reference.id, reference.slide_id, reference.group_id
))
print('reference2 with id %s was created. slide_id = %s, group_id = %s' % (
    reference2.id, reference2.slide_id, reference2.group_id
))

reference = Reference.query.filter_by(id=reference.id).first()
print('add reference with id = %s to delete' % reference.id)
db.session.delete(reference)
print('amount references after delete: %s' % Reference.query.all())
db.session.commit()
```

You will see that in first case `Preference`, `Group` and `Slide` were deleted. Because other `Preference`’s didn't related to `Group` and `Slide`. But in the second case you will see that only `Preference` was removed:

```
reference with id 76 was created. slide_id = 65, group_id = 65
add reference with id = 76 to delete
add slide with id = 65 to delete
add group with id = 65 to delete
amount references after delete: []
reference with id 77 was created. slide_id = 66, group_id = 66
reference2 with id 78 was created. slide_id = 66, group_id = 66
add reference with id = 77 to delete
# with slide_id = 66, group_id = 66
amount references after delete: [<Reference 78>]
```

Hope this helps.